# Como deixar que só usuarios registrados vejam o link?

Tags: php

Tenho um site que já tem acesso restrito a usuários logados para postar link. mas não estou conseguindo fazer que os links postados fiquem visíveis somente também para usuários registrados, por favor toda a ajuda é bem vinda.

Segue código:

```
$register    = get_option('dt_register_user');
$idts        = get_post_meta($post->ID, "dt_string", $single = true); 
$return        =  return_links( $idts );
if($return == 1) {
?>

<div class="linktabs">
    <h2><?php _d('Links'); ?></h2>
    <ul class="idTabs">
        <?php /* set 1 */ if(count_type_link($idts, __d('Download')) == 1) { echo '<li><a href="#downloads">'. __d('Download'). '</a></li>'; } ?>
        <?php /* set 2 */ if(count_type_link($idts, __d('Torrent'))  == 1) { echo '<li><a href="#torrent">'. __d('Torrent'). '</a></li>'; } ?>
        <?php /* set 3 */ if(count_type_link($idts, __d('Watch online'))  == 1) { echo '<li><a href="#views">'. __d('ASSISTIR ONLINE CLIQUE ABAIXO'). '</a></li>'; } ?>
    </ul>
</div>

<?php if(count_type_link($idts, __d('Download'))  == 1) { ?>
<div id="downloads" class="sbox">
    <div class="links_table">
        <?php get_dt_links( $idts, __d('Download') ); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } if(count_type_link($idts, __d('Torrent') )  == 1) { ?>
<div id="torrent" class="sbox">
    <div class="links_table">
        <?php get_dt_links( $idts, __d('Torrent') ); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } if(count_type_link($idts, __d('Watch online') )  == 1) { ?>
<div id="views" class="sbox">
    <div class="links_table">
        <?php get_dt_links( $idts, __d('Watch online') ); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } } if( is_user_logged_in() ) {  ?>
<div id="form" class="sbox">
    <div class="links_table">
        <?php get_template_part('inc/parts/form_links'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } elseif($register == 'true') { ?>
<div id="form" class="sbox">
    <div id="resultado_link_form">
        <div class="msg"><i class="icon-notification"></i><a class="clicklogin"><?php _d('Entrar'); ?></a> <?php _d('para postar links'); ?></div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cara a questão ai é a seguinte, você precisa verificar se a SESSAO do usuario esta aberta para exibir os links, vou te dar um exemplo

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logado']) == true){
        include './menu/menulogado.php';
    }else{
        include './menu/menu.php';
    }
```

nesse caso quando meu usuario faz login eu crio a session logado, e qquando ele esta na pagina eu verifico se é verdadeiro para carregar o menu correto, no seu caso vc trocaria pelos urls